# Extend lists in python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
x = [0,2]
y = [['1','2','1'],['5','5','5','2','1']]
```

I initialize a new list which should contain two lists:

```
z = []
```

I would like list "z" to look like this:

```
[[0,1,2],[2,3,4,5,6]]
```

As you can see, both lists inside list "z" has as many 1-incremental elements as the number of elements in list "y". Let me try and be more clear:

1. you take the first element of list "x", which is 0;
2. I want to increment that value of 0 by 1, by as many elements as is the number of elements in the first occurrence of list "y": in this example, the first occurrence of list "y" has 3 occurrences, so I'd like to get: [0,1,2]
3. you take the second element of list "x", which is 2;
4. I want to increment that value of 2 by 1, by as many elements as is the number of elements in the second occurrence of list "y": in this example, the second occurrence of list "y" has 5 occurrences, so I'd like to get: [2,3,4,5,6]
5. Then I want to combine the two lists into one list called "z", such that "z" looks like this:

   [[0,1,2],[2,3,4,5,6]]

Does the question make sense?

I have tried this code:

```
x = [0,2]
y = [['1','2','1'],['5','5','5','2','1']]
z = []


l = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    z.append(l)
    for j in range(len(y[i])):
        print(j)
        l.append(x[i]+j)


print(z)
```

But I get this result:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You're misusing/reusing the list `l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not reuse `l`:

> ```
> for i in range(len(y)):
>     l = []                     # moved inside so its a fresh l
>     z.append(l)                # and not the same l-reference
>     for j in range(len(y[i])): # reused
>         print(j)
>         l.append(x[i]+j)
> ```

This can be achieved using enumerating over `x` and some indexing into `y`:

```
x = [0,2]
y = [['1','2','1'],['5','5','5','2','1']]

z = [list(range(k, k + len(y[idx]))) for idx, k in enumerate(x)]

print(z)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

which is equivalent to

```
x = [0,2]
y = [['1','2','1'],['5','5','5','2','1']]
z = []

for idx,value in enumerate(x):
    z.append( list(range(value, value + len(y[idx]))))

print(z)
```